How to prevent Kafka warning message cycle
Apache Kafka CLI command to be run with --list throws the warning
WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

and makes it cyclically will not yet Ctrl + C pressed.
How to prevent cycling and out the message one time with appropriate exit code I can use later?

For a a generalised solution not specific to kafka, you could use timeout.
e.g.
timeout 10s kafkasomething --list

That would exit with 124 if the timeout was reached -- but it wouldn't tell you any more than that on its own.  You could capture the output and process it to help you determine the failure cause.
e.g.
tempfile="$(mktemp)"
timeout 10s kafkasomething --list | tee "${tempfile:?}"
result=$?
case $result in
  (0)
    echo 'Command OK'
    ;;
  (124)
    grep -F 'Broker may not be available' "${tempfile}" && echo 'Broker not available'
    grep -F 'foo' "${tempfile}" && echo 'Found a foo'
    ;;
  (*)
    echo "Unhandled result: $result"
  ;;
esac

rm "${tempfile}"

